# How to pass option values to a button

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, variables

I'm trying to store variables from select/option, and then access them from a button to send to a javascript function that would filter some divs on my page.

So far I have it sending the value to "filter()" when the value changes.
Here's my markup:

```
<select name="Area" onchange="filter(this)">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option value="Austin">Austin</option>
    <option value="San Antonio">San Antonio</option>
    <option value="Temple">Temple</option>
</select>
<select name="Number" onchange="filter(this)">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<a class="button">Submit</a>
```

but how do I store the values from all the options, and then send them
all at once to the function?

Edit: In other words, how do I store the value of each option, and only send to the function once they click submit?

Comment: what your needs when submitting button ,option value passed into your button or else what your expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right, without jQuery you may try this:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    var selects = document.body.getElementsByTagName("select");
    var data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        data.push(selects[i].value);
    }

    destinyFunction(data);
};
```

Or you may use jQuery for the sake of simplicity:

```
$("#jbutton").on("click", function() {
    var data = [];

    $("select").each(function() {
        data.push($(this).val());
    });

    destinyFunction(data);
});
```

Fiddle with those two examples [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6U7Pn/).

Comment: That's exactly it! I knew I had to use an array, and some kind of function onclick - I just didn't know how to put it all together. This helps a ton, thanks!

Comment: @BrunoVeiga nice, but do changes to make that code better, its too generic. Put some validation on the select value and select the elements in a better way instead of `document.body.getElementsByTagName`, this's a poor way.

Answer (score 2):

Give each of your selects an id attribute, like:

```
<select name="Number" onchange="filter(this)" id="Number">
...
```

Then you can get the value of each in javascript by:

```
var el = document.getElementById('Number');
var value = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
```

As a sidenote, using `onchange` in HTML markup to attach your event handling is not best practice.  [This article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) from quirksmode offers a good explanation of alternative solutions.  However, there are major cross-browser considerations to be taken into account, which is why most people prefer to use a Javascript framework so that those are mostly mitigated.